# Using Multiple Qt Resources, One Internal & One External

Tags: qt, resources, external, internal

I would like to use a set of internal resources and external resources at the same time. I have read and re-read the Qt Resource System document and the QResource class document and still don't really understand how to use the external resources and if I can use both an internal resource and an external resource at the same time. I could find no real examples of using external resources. I have the internal resources working and now want to add an external resource that changes depending on a user selected unit to work on. So I guess I have the following questions:

1. Can use use both an internal and external resource at the same time?
2. Do you need to instantiate a QResource object explicitly at any time?
3. I have read where you call "QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc");" to register and external resource but then how do access a particular file in that resource?
4. How are the internal and external resources distinguished from each other if they have similar paths?

As I said, I just could not find any good examples to help me down this path. Thanks for any help resolving these questions.

Comment: Try to read Qt documentation. There are all answers to your questions.

Comment: I did read everything I could find about the resources, I could not find answers or examples to these questions. I don't post until I have exhausted the Qt site and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Once you register your resources using `QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc")` you can use those resources the same way you would any other resource. If you have multiple resources that may conflict in identification you have to load each resource to a different virtual location by including a second argument to the path like so `QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc", "/virtual/path")`

Comment: Thank you.  This helped solve my issue.  I have been able to work my way through almost all of my Qt issues but to me the resources seem minimally documented compared to other topics.